# Is it possible to search & delete ALL shortcuts pointing to an EXE using C#?

Tags: c#, windows, shortcut

So I distributed a piece of software (Patcher.exe). We now need to rename the Patcher.exe to SystemPatcher.exe.

However, we would like to minimize (if not completely avoid) shortcut issues.

To do so... I would like to make a new C# program, named the same as the original Patcher.exe and have it search & delete ALL shortcuts pointing to Patcher.exe. It will then create a new shortcut to SystemPatcher.exe on the users desktop, and notify them of the change.

I can do the last bits, but my issue is I don't know if it's possible to search the users computer for ALL shortcuts pointing to Patcher.exe and delete them.

Is this possible? Does anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this in C#?

P.S No having the old Patcher.exe simply launch SystemPatcher.exe is NOT an option (it causes issues with other software for some reason).

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Are you asking us to do it for you, or...? Perhaps you should also consider how a program can search the desktops of every user. If your system allows that, you should probably be more worried about security. If not, consider that you'll need to install this theoretical program on every computer individually.

Comment: We wouldn't install it individually, as the name of the software is titled.. It's a Patching software. No I'm not asking for you to do it, just a push in the direction.

Comment: I think the shortcuts should be managed by the installer, have a look about InstallShield or advanced installer (there are many others), the installer should generate shortcuts, registry keys and so on, then when you update your software you can generate a patch that updates all shortcuts, etc..

Comment: This wouldn't account for user generated shortcuts though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate all .lnk files with your user privileges.

```
void Main()
{
    SearchAndDestroy("c:\\");
}

static void SearchAndDestroy(string folder)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.lnk"), file =>
     {
        try
         {

             if (File.ReadLines(file).Any(line => line.Contains("your.exe")))
             {
                 // delete it
             }
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {

             // inaccesible file
         }
     });

    Parallel.ForEach(Directory.GetDirectories(folder), subDir =>
     {
         try
         {
             SearchAndDestroy(subDir);
         }
         catch
         {
             // inaccesible dir.
         }
     });
}
```

Comment: That'll do it, thanks.